# how to display timestamp without timezone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time, timezone

@object.updated_at.localtime displays "2015-04-20 14:39:27 -0700". I don't want to display the -0700, is there a method that will strip out the timezone for display purposes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ignoring timezones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-timezones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql)

Comment: that's a great question and answer, but the scope is *much* larger than my question here... I really just needed help on the syntax for formatting .localtime. the answer I got was perfect.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
@object.updated_at.localtime.strftime '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
```

Answer (score 6):

If you plan to use that format across your app, you might as well create a new time format:

```
# config/initializers/time_formats.rb
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:no_timezone] = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
```

Then just use it like this:

```
Time.now.to_s(:no_timezone)
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use `I18n.l` and define a format in. your language.yml

```
I18n.l @object.updated_at, format: :my_format
```

## en.yml

```
en:
  time:
    formats:
      myformat: "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"
```